# Jinja2 list index variable - list_name[variable]

Tags: python-3.x, list, jinja2

I'm trying to pass on the variable, `prod_number`, to the index of a list, `products`.

```
<div class="container">
{% for i in range(lenProducts) %}
    <ul class="row product-grid">
            {% for j in range(0, 3) %}
                <br>
                <p class="text-primary"> {% set prod_number = i*3+j %} </p>
                <li class="col-md-4 product-wrapper card">
                    {{ products[prod_number].id }}
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

`{{ products[prod_number].id }}` This line makes the page load forever

How can I fix this? I've isolated the problem and I'm 100% sure it's from that line.

Comment: try using {{ products[prod_number]['id'] }}

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work :

```
<div class="container">
{% for i in range(lenProducts) %}
    <ul class="row product-grid">
            {% for j in range(0, 3) %}
                <br>
                <p class="text-primary"> {% set prod_number = (i*3)+j %} </p>
                <li class="col-md-4 product-wrapper card">
                    {{ products[prod_number]['id'] }}
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Same thing. The problem is from the [prod_number] probably

Comment: I tested almost all combinations and I also tried using products[0].id and it works that way. Though, what I need is to use a variable but doesn't seem to work the way I coded it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the `prod_number` exceeded the `products` length and it caused my page to load forever.

`prod_number` went from 0 to 17 and `products` had only 6 elements in it.